# Is this layout possible in CSS?

Tags: html, css, width, fluid-layout

I have a layout that looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pWmBj/2/.
However, when `.active` is toggled on, I would like `#par.active>div` to have the following properties:

1. min-width: 100% of container (#par)
2. max-width: 300px (unless #par width > 300px -- I'm assuming that's the default behavior for min-width)
3. width: auto

The problem is that `#par.active>div` never seems to care about the `width:auto` CSS. I would like it to expand to its natural width, but it stays constrained to its parent width (#par).

Comment: It would appear this layout isn't possible without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark:

`<div>`'s are block-level elements - by default, they will assume the width of their parent.

You could try:

```
#par.active>div {
 ...
 display: inline-block;
}
```

I tried it on your JSFiddle, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the effect you're after.

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FPWRV/. Except, where `#par.active>div` is position:absolute and min-width:100% of #par.